# Unable to 'share' URL on Facebook and Twitter native apps on Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, firefox-os

This is the first time that I am exploring the share functionality for sharing a URL on Facebook / Twitter native apps and I would appreciate some help to get this functionality working.

I checked and noticed that the boilerplate app doest actually work in this case. [Issues reported on GitHub with snapshots](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App/issues).

Basically the issue is that these social networking apps are not getting the URLs that are sent through `MozActivity`.

Has anyone faced this issue before? How do I resolve this?

Here is the Firefox OS app code that I have so far (pretty much similar to boilerplate app):

JS:

```
"use strict";
(function () {

    var share = document.querySelector("#share");
    if (share) {
        share.onclick = function () {
            new MozActivity({
                name: "share",
                data: {
                    url: "http://www.google.com"
                }
            });
        };
    }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <button id="share">Share URL</button>
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webapp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

> **MozActivity**
>
> This API is available on Firefox or Firefox OS for installed or higher
>   privileged applications.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozActivity

Define in your `manifest.json`:

```
"type": "privileged"
```